# PayPal Open SSL exception certificate B verify failed - rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, paypal

I'm trying to get my PayPal live settings to work and keep getting this error when attempting to purchase with PayPal on my site:

```
Exception Type: OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError Exception Message: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed REQUEST
```

I have a cacert.pem file and it definitely exists in the correct location on my application. I'm not sure what the issue is?

Thanks

Comment: To few details but it might be the same problem as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27804710/python-urllib2-ssl-error/27826829#27826829). ruby also uses OpenSSL and is affected by the the problem.

Comment: Are you using SSL v3 on your server? SSL v3 has been found insecure and is not supported by paypal any more since beginning of this year. You would need to use TLS instead. Sandbox won't work with SSL v3 either. But I'm not sure, because SSL v3 would return a handshake error. So ignore me if this is not the case...

Comment: sorry, didn't know what else to provide :/. Sandbox is working fine it's just when live that the error appears