# How do add SSL certificate to python 2.7.9

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, ssl

I recently upgraded to python 2.7.9, and I'm experiencing all sorts of SSL errors:

```
.SSL verification error: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590)
```

I paid for an SSL certificate, how do I set it up so that python stops complaining. I received a .crt file, how do I convert that to a .pem? Also, is there any way to fix this globally, such that I don't have to go and change all my all code?

Thanks!

FYI, when I type this: conda install python=2.7.7, I get these errors:

```
Fetching package metadata: SSL verification error: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590)
SSL verification error: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590)
.SSL verification error: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590)
SSL verification error: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590)
```

so this has nothing to do with any specific URLs, it's a configuration issue, and my question is how do I tell python where to look for my .crt files.

Comment: What server, what OS, what code?

Comment: running on Ubuntu 14, all of my code that makes outgoing requests to https URLs now fail.

Comment: Which https urls, just the one on your server or ALL https urls?  Please update your question with all the details.

Comment: It could be a duplicate of  [“SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED” Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27835619/ssl-certificate-verify-failed-error)

Comment: it's not a duplicate because I want to solve the problem, I'm not looking for a work-around. There is no actual solution posted in that link, just a hack. How do I tell python that my .crt file is located at pathX, so this problem is solved. That's the question!

Comment: You need the .crt installed on the server, your python application need to use the .pem supplied by your registrar, if you can't read past the first answer which would have pointed you to [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27804710/2904896) and code (`urllib2.urlopen(req, cafile="verisign.pem")`)

Comment: is there any way to define it globally, I can't possibly rewrite all my functions to include "cafile="verisign.pem""

Comment: This then becomes a system administration issue, see: [What should I do about Python 2.7.9 not looking for SSL certificates in the right place on FreeBSD?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/176294/what-should-i-do-about-python-2-7-9-not-looking-for-ssl-certificates-in-the-righ) for the solution to similar problem (`ssl.get_default_verify_paths()`)

Comment: (updated) I would like to see a proper solution as well and not a workaround. Would be great to have a store to put known certificates like when using ssh for known certificates.