# requests SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED with verify="./cabundle.crt"

Tags: python, ssl, https, python-requests

### Problem

Short description: python requests keep throwing SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED when connecting to server with own cabundle:

```
In [1]:  import requests
In [3]: requests.get('https://activeo.monitowl.com', verify=True)      
Out[3]: <Response [200]>
In [4]: requests.get('https://activeo.monitowl.com', verify="./ca_bundle.crt")
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
SSLError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-c92a3091d6ce> in <module>()
----> 1 requests.get('https://activeo.monitowl.com', verify="./ca_bundle.crt")

/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.pyc in get(url, params, **kwargs)
     67 
     68     kwargs.setdefault('allow_redirects', True)
---> 69     return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
     70 
     71 

/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.pyc in request(method, url, **kwargs)
     48 
     49     session = sessions.Session()
---> 50     response = session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
     51     # By explicitly closing the session, we avoid leaving sockets open which
     52     # can trigger a ResourceWarning in some cases, and look like a memory leak

/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.pyc in request(self, method, url, params, data, headers, cookies, files, auth, timeout, allow_redirects, proxies, hooks, stream, verify, cert, json)
    463         }
    464         send_kwargs.update(settings)
--> 465         resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
    466 
    467         return resp

/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.pyc in send(self, request, **kwargs)
    571 
    572         # Send the request
--> 573         r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
    574 
    575         # Total elapsed time of the request (approximately)

/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.pyc in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    429         except (_SSLError, _HTTPError) as e:
    430             if isinstance(e, _SSLError):
--> 431                 raise SSLError(e, request=request)
    432             elif isinstance(e, ReadTimeoutError):
    433                 raise ReadTimeout(e, request=request)

SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:581)

In [5]: requests.get('https://activeo.monitowl.com', verify="./ca_bundle_ff.crt")    
[same error]
In [7]:  import ssl; ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION
Out[7]: 'OpenSSL 1.0.1k 8 Jan 2015'
In [8]: import sys; print (sys.version)
2.7.9 (default, Mar  1 2015, 12:57:24) 
[GCC 4.9.2]
In [2]: requests.__version__
Out[2]: '2.7.0'
```

### Story

We are using requests in [MonitOwl](https://github.com/whitehats/monitowl-agent) agent to communicate with API servers. Few days ago we ordered new certificates for *.monitowl.com and deployed it to new instance, our issuer is `nazwa.pl`. Pointing a webbrowser to https://activeo.monitowl.com works flawlessly, requests seems to have some problems, when setting verify="./cabundle.crt".

### Technical notes

In front of the tornado server handling ssl there is a "transparent" haproxy checking SNI and redistributing the traffic, part of the config file:

```
acl app_activeo req_ssl_sni -i activeo.monitowl.com
use_backend bk_activeo if app_activeo
```

We *need* to provide own cabundle to have control what is accepted - because of security issues and deployment scripts. We are using debian jessie everywhere.

I've tested the server with [ssl checker](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=activeo.monitowl.com) and there was no issues, beside accepting old crypto algorithms..

```
# from issuer https://panel.nazwa.pl/uploads/ssl/nazwaSSL_SHA-2.zip
$ cat monitowlcom.crt nazwasslsha2.pem certumca-ctncasha2.pem gscasha2.pem > ./ca_bundle.crt
# exported from firefox
$ cat monitowl.com nazwaSSL CertumTrustedNetworkCA CertumGlobalServicesCASHA2 > ca_bundle_ff.crt
$  openssl verify -untrusted ./ca.crt  monitowlcom.crt 
monitowlcom.crt: OK
$ c_rehash ./
$ openssl s_client -CApath ./  -connect activeo.monitowl.com:443 -servername activeo.monitowl.com
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=4 C = PL, O = Unizeto Sp. z o.o., CN = Certum CA
verify return:1
depth=3 C = PL, O = Unizeto Technologies S.A., OU = Certum Certification Authority, CN = Certum Trusted Network CA
verify return:1
depth=2 C = PL, O = Unizeto Technologies S.A., OU = Certum Certification Authority, CN = Certum Global Services CA SHA2
verify return:1
depth=1 C = PL, O = nazwa.pl S.A., OU = http://nazwa.pl, CN = nazwaSSL
verify return:1
depth=0 C = PL, CN = *.monitowl.com, emailAddress = ***@whitehats.pl
verify return:1
[...]
*    Verify return code: 0 (ok)*

$ curl -I --cacert ca_bundle.crt https://activeo.monitowl.com 
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
$ curl -I --cacert ca_bundle_ff.crt https://activeo.monitowl.com 
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

As you can see, the `openssl s_client` verifies the connection, curl works without problems.

On server side (tornado):

 `SSLError: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_UNKNOWN_CA] tlsv1 alert unknown ca (_ssl.c:581)`

I asked some friends to test it with the bundle exported from web browser and:

```
Python==2.7.9 + OpenSSL==1.0.1k => FAILS
Python==2.7.10 + OpenSSL==1.0.1k => FAILS
Python==2.7.9 + OpenSSL==1.0.1l => FAILS
Python==2.7.10 + OpenSSL==1.0.1p => WORKS
Python==2.7.10 + OpenSSL==1.0.2d => WORKS
Python==2.7.9 + OpenSSL 1.0.2d  => WORKS
```

I'm aware that python verifies the certs [differently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27804710/python-urllib2-ssl-error/27826829#27826829) than web browsers, but looks like it's not the thing here.

### Question

Do you have any clues what is wrong with the bundle? 
What else can I check?

It's a bug? In requests, openssl, python or urllib3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Lukasa](https://github.com/Lukasa) (one of requests collaborators) pointed, the issue is becuase of poor support for cross signed chains in python:

> The problem with the SHA256 bundle is that the 'root' cert in that case is cross-signed with the SHA-1 cert, but older OpenSSL's wont like that at all. The way older OpenSSL builds a cert chain is that it builds the longest one it can out of the certs provided by the remote server, and then looks for a trusted certificate that signs that chain. If it can't find that certificate, it'll bail out, without checking whether it can build a shorter chain using its trust roots.
>
> This is an ongoing problem with the deprecation of SHA1 root certs: see [certifi/python-certifi#26](https://github.com/certifi/python-certifi/issues/26). Unfortunately, the only fixes are to temporarily use the SHA1 root in your trust store or to upgrade to a newer OpenSSL version.

https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/2783

So as a temporary fix, I have included the SHA1 path too in my cabundle:

```
 cat ca_sha1.crt ca_sha256.crt > cabundle.crt
```

Answer (score 0):

dont use your ca bundle file. try to use `verify=True` and paste content of your cert file to the bottom of /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/cacert.pem, the location depends on your Linux version or dist (CentOS, Debian, etc..). Please use `find / -name requests` to locate where the requests installed in your system, then find out cacert.pem.

This is because Requests use this cacert.pem as its own ca bundle by default.

If that does not work, then you should get the high level issuer cert as cert file.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but because of security reasons I cannot use the system/certifi certs, need to allow only certificates signed by one (trusted) CA. As I pointed before, with `verity=True` it works flawlessly but it's not what I need.