# I am having trouble downloading nltk's punkt tokenizer

Tags: python, nltk

I'm trying to download punkt, but I'm getting the following error...

```
>>> import nltk
>>> nltk.download('punkt')
>>> [nltk_data] Error loading punkt: <urlopen error [SSL] unknown error
>>> [nltk_data]     (_ssl.c:590)>
>>> False
>>>
```

can someone please help I've been trying for days...

Comment: which version of python you are using?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess the downloader script is broken. As a temporal workaround can manually download the punkt tokenizer from [here](http://www.nltk.org/nltk_data/) and then place the unzipped folder in the corresponding location. The default folders for each OS are:

- Windows: `C:\nltk_data\tokenizers`
- OSX: `/usr/local/share/nltk_data/tokenizers`
- Unix: `/usr/share/nltk_data/tokenizers`

I am not sure but you may find this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33142108/5352399) helpful.

Comment: thank you for your help, i can't seem to be able to download the Punkt Tokenizer Models, nothing happens?

Comment: what!! you can't download it from website as well? what problem you are facing?

Comment: i don't know what to say, i have downloaded to check if there is any problem but it worked. not sure why you are facing problem? can you download other things from web? try clearing the cache of your browser!

Comment: I've cleared cache but still no luck, other things seem to download fine. I can't download it through other browsers either

Comment: I have shared it in my google drive - https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bwdcsp1RitZbN1RvVnRTV3NqdEU/view?usp=sharing. try to download it. once you are done, let me know. i will remove that :)

Comment: one more thing... i need Averaged Perceptron Tagger as well but i can't download it

Comment: best way to thank is accepting the answer :) by the way, I have shared the perceptron tagger here - https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bwdcsp1RitZbZXRUZGRra3hQYjg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: chunkers/maxent_ne_chunker/english_ace_binary.pickle?

Comment: download Named Entity Chunker - https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bwdcsp1RitZbVUo2TXZHbUlnMGc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: thanks, what folder would i put that in? this seems more complicated that it should be because i can't download things myself

Comment: everything should be inside `nltk_folder` - as far as i know :)

Comment: corpora/words? could you get this for me?

Comment: I have shared the entire nltk_data folder which is installed in my machine here - https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bwdcsp1RitZbYkdfTDN5Zm9UdTQ/view?usp=sharing. i can't download and share anything more than that.

Comment: how did you download the whole file as one thing?

Comment: `import nltk` and then `nltk.download()` which is not working for you unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

Though this is an old question, I had the same issue on my mac today. The solution [here](https://github.com/sloria/TextBlob/issues/133#issuecomment-338844284) helped me solve it.

Edit:

Run the following command on the OSX before running nltk.download():

```
/Applications/Python\ PYTHON_VERSION_HERE/Install\ Certificates.command
```

Comment: The solution mentioned in the GitHub seems to be ok, but links happen to expire so it's better to avoid _link-only_ answers.  Please edit your answer to cite most important details.of the solution.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is detailed instruction to install `punkt` manually if `nltk.download()` doesn't work for you.

**Context**: I tried to use `nltk.word_tokenize()` and it throwed the error:

```
LookupError: 
**********************************************************************
  Resource punkt not found.
  Please use the NLTK Downloader to obtain the resource:

  >>> import nltk
  >>> nltk.download('punkt')
  
  For more information see: https://www.nltk.org/data.html

  Attempted to load tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle

  Searched in:
    - 'C:\\Users\\username/nltk_data'
    - 'C:\\Users\\username\\anaconda3\\envs\\conda-env\\nltk_data'
```

**Solution**: to download the package manually.

**Step 1**: Look up corresponding corpus in http://www.nltk.org/nltk_data/. For example, it's *Punkt Tokenizer Models* in this case; click download and store in one of the folder mentioned above (if `nltk_data` folder does not exist, create one). For me, I picked 'C:\Users\username/nltk_data'.

**Step 2**: Notice that it said "Attempted to load tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle", that means you must create the same folder structure. I created "tokenizers" folder inside "nltk_data", then copy the unzipped content inside and ensure the file path "C:/Users/username/nltk_data/tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle" valid.

Answer (score 0):

On laptop windows OS, I was not able to download on wifi network (that is, nltk.download('gutenberg') on python idle was not working. It gave connection attempt failed error). But when I gave my Android realme C25s Airtel hotspot to my laptop, it worked. So, I think issue might be in internet connection. Change your internet connection to a more faster and stable one, in particular, which unlike wifi has a longer range of network connection.