# SSLError: bad handshake, Python requests

Tags: python, django, ssl, python-requests, ebay-api

I am consuming [Ebay Trading APIs](http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/reference/ebay/index.html) using [Ebay python sdk](https://github.com/timotheus/ebaysdk-python) which is eventually sing [python-requests](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests) for making API calls.

All was working fine, but since last few days I am unable to make call. I am getting error:

```
SSLError: bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE', 'certificate verify failed')],)
```

Here is complete traceback:

```
In [9]: response = api.execute('GetSessionID', data)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
SSLError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-eb33610c2a7f> in <module>()
----> 1 response = api.execute('GetSessionID', data)

/home/debian/.virtualenvs/myvirtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ebaysdk/connection.pyc in execute(self, verb, data, list_nodes, verb_attrs, files)
    117
    118         self.build_request(verb, data, verb_attrs, files)
--> 119         self.execute_request()
    120
    121         if hasattr(self.response, 'content'):

/home/debian/.virtualenvs/goplaces/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ebaysdk/connection.pyc in execute_request(self)
    182             proxies=self.proxies,
    183             timeout=self.timeout,
--> 184             allow_redirects=True
    185         )
    186

/home/debian/.virtualenvs/myvirtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.pyc in send(self, request, **kwargs)
    574
    575         # Send the request
--> 576         r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
    577
    578         # Total elapsed time of the request (approximately)

/home/debian/.virtualenvs/myvirtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.pyc in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    431         except (_SSLError, _HTTPError) as e:
    432             if isinstance(e, _SSLError):
--> 433                 raise SSLError(e, request=request)
    434             elif isinstance(e, ReadTimeoutError):
    435                 raise ReadTimeout(e, request=request)

SSLError: bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE', 'certificate verify failed')],)
```

There are many related question on StackOverflow, all which says:

1. pass argument verify=False
2. pass CA certificate
3. append you CA certificate in [cacert.pem file](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/requests/cacert.pem)  (I tried this, didn't work)

I can not do this because:

1. requests is being called by third-party library which is in my virtualenvirinent.
2. This is bad in security point of view.

Also,

1. I am able to make other TSL calls  (e.g.  Amazon marketplace apis) in the same virtualenv using requests, which not causing bad handshake or any other SSL errors.
2. Ebay SDK is working fine on my local system(Mac OsX), issue is only with my production server (Google Cloud/Debian)
3. There are no SSL errors reported by chrome on my domain

I have no knowledge why this is happening.

Why `SSL routines', 'SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE', 'certificate verify failed'` is in traceback, when I have disabled SSL3. (I have no deep knowledge about SSL).

Thank you!

### Edit:

```
# openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.2e 3 Dec 2015
```

Upgraded to openssl 1.0.2 from 1.0.1 by building from source after @Steffen Ullrich's suggestion.

```
$ pip freeze | grep -i ssl
backports.ssl-match-hostname==3.4.0.2
pyOpenSSL==0.15.1
```

Comment: There is no such code to show, I am just calling [execute method](https://github.com/timotheus/ebaysdk-python/blob/master/ebaysdk/connection.py#L106)  of [Connection Class](https://github.com/timotheus/ebaysdk-python/blob/master/ebaysdk/trading/__init__.py#L17).
You can check traceback I pasted in my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is this is related to [Python Urllib2 SSL error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27804710/python-urllib2-ssl-error/27826829#27826829), i.e. a problem of multiple trust path in the underlying implementation of OpenSSL. See there for the details of the problem.

To fix this without making changes to your trusted CA's you would need to have a fixed OpenSSL, i.e. OpenSSL 1.0.2. Or you could add some of the older CA certificates back to your trust store.

> 1. pass argument verify=False
> 2. pass CA certificate
> 3. append you CA certificate in cacert.pem file (I tried this, didn't work)
>
> ...
> This is bad in security point of view.

While `verify=False` is bad for security because it disables validation the other options are not bad because they only add additional trust anchors but keep validation enabled.

> Why SSL routines', 'SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE', 'certificate verify failed' is in traceback, when I have disabled SSL3.

Even if it talks about SSLv3 there it does not mean it. TLS and SSLv3 share a lot of functionality, i.e. TLS 1.0 is actually SSL 3.1. Thus lots of the `SSL3_*` functions in the OpenSSL code are used with TLS 1.x too which causes these irritating messages.

Comment: Upgraded to openssl 1.0.2 , problem stil persist. I want to point out that I am able to make request to other apis, e.g. amazon from same virtualenv.

Comment: @electropoet: Can you share a minimal working example so that one could reproduce your problem? For now it is just guessing what the problem might be.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's related to this section of https://pypi.python.org/pypi/certifi/

> **1024-bit Root Certificates**
>
> Browsers and certificate authorities have
>   concluded that 1024-bit keys are unacceptably weak for certificates,
>   particularly root certificates. For this reason, Mozilla has removed
>   any weak (i.e. 1024-bit key) certificate from its bundle, replacing it
>   with an equivalent strong (i.e. 2048-bit or greater key) certifiate
>   from the same CA. Because Mozilla removed these certificates from its
>   bundle, certifi removed them as well.
>
> Unfortunately, old versions of OpenSSL (less than 1.0.2) sometimes
>   fail to validate certificate chains that use the strong roots. For
>   this reason, if you fail to validate a certificate using the
>   certifi.where() mechanism, you can intentionally re-add the 1024-bit
>   roots back into your bundle by calling certifi.old_where() instead.
>   This is not recommended in production: if at all possible you should
>   upgrade to a newer OpenSSL. However, if you have no other option, this
>   may work for you.

My test goes like this:

```
root@43b7ec35c240:/usr/src/app# cat /etc/debian_version
8.2
root@43b7ec35c240:/usr/src/app# cat test.py
import logging

import requests

logging.basicConfig()
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
requests_log = logging.getLogger("requests.packages.urllib3")
requests_log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
requests_log.propagate = True

requests.get('https://www.google.com/')
root@43b7ec35c240:/usr/src/app# python test.py
INFO:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): www.google.com
DEBUG:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:"GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 263
INFO:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): www.google.com.hk
DEBUG:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:"GET /?gfe_rd=cr&ei=XXKbVqqBD8WM8Qe3v7-YAQ HTTP/1.1" 200 None
root@43b7ec35c240:/usr/src/app# openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.1k 8 Jan 2015
root@43b7ec35c240:/usr/src/app# pip install certifi
Collecting certifi
  Using cached certifi-2015.11.20.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: certifi
Successfully installed certifi-2015.11.20.1
root@43b7ec35c240:/usr/src/app# python test.py
INFO:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): www.google.com
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 16, in <module>
    requests.get('https://www.google.com/')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 69, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 50, in request
    response = session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 468, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 576, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 433, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590)
root@43b7ec35c240:/usr/src/app# pip uninstall certifi
Uninstalling certifi-2015.11.20.1:
  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/certifi-2015.11.20.1.dist-info/DESCRIPTION.rst
  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/certifi-2015.11.20.1.dist-info/METADATA
  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/certifi-2015.11.20.1.dist-info/RECORD
  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/certifi-2015.11.20.1.dist-info/WHEEL
  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/certifi-2015.11.20.1.dist-info/metadata.json
  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/certifi-2015.11.20.1.dist-info/top_level.txt
  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/certifi/__init__.py
  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/certifi/__init__.pyc
  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/certifi/__main__.py
  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/certifi/__main__.pyc
  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/certifi/cacert.pem
  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/certifi/core.py
  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/certifi/core.pyc
  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/certifi/old_root.pem
  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/certifi/weak.pem
Proceed (y/n)? y
  Successfully uninstalled certifi-2015.11.20.1
root@43b7ec35c240:/usr/src/app# python test.py
INFO:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): www.google.com
DEBUG:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:"GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 263
INFO:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): www.google.com.hk
DEBUG:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:"GET /?gfe_rd=cr&ei=AnObVtG4BcGM8QeC6r-YCw HTTP/1.1" 200 None
```

Then I try to update my libssl package by doing:

```
# curl http://apt.wikimedia.org/autoinstall/keyring/wikimedia-archive-keyring.gpg | apt-key add -

# echo "deb http://apt.wikimedia.org/wikimedia jessie-wikimedia backports" >> /etc/apt/sources.list

# apt-get update
# apt-get install libssl1.0.0

# openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.1k 8 Jan 2015 (Library: OpenSSL 1.0.2e 3 Dec 2015)
```

After that, even with certifi installed, I am all good.

```
# pip freeze |grep certifi
certifi==2015.11.20.1

# python test.py
INFO:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): www.google.com
DEBUG:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:"GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 263
INFO:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): www.google.com.hk
DEBUG:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:"GET /?gfe_rd=cr&ei=4XSbVt2gK8OM8Qe1tICIBA HTTP/1.1" 200 None
```