# SSLError using pip install (to install tensorflow)

Tags: python, ssl, installation, pip, ssl-certificate

while installing TF, exception appeared:

> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/adapter.py",
>   line 46, in send
>   resp = super(CacheControlAdapter, self).send(request, **kw)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/adapters.py",
>   line 447, in send
>   raise SSLError(e, request=request) SSLError: ("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE', 'certificate
>   verify failed')],)",)

```
command: pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.6.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
```

I have no clue how to solve this. I was recently reinstalled pip, could reinstall cause it?

Comment: The error indicates a problem with the remote site's certificate. It could be misconfigured, or there could be something in your network (proxy? wlan?) which intercepts the traffic somehow. Can you fetch the URL manually, e.g.  with `curl`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

*SSL error can be solved by bellow steps for sure. Just download the wheel on your own and pip install.*

**# Ubuntu/Linux 64-bit, CPU only:**

$ wget https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.5.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl

$ sudo pip install --upgrade tensorflow-0.5.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl

**# Ubuntu/Linux 64-bit, GPU enabled:**

$ wget https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/gpu/tensorflow-0.5.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl

$ sudo pip install --upgrade tensorflow-0.5.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl

Comment: Thanks! But to be honest, this doesn't solve the SSL error, it's just a bypass.

Answer (score 4):

Use the following version of certifi

```
pip2 install 'certifi==2015.4.28' --force-reinstall
```

after that there will be no more SSL errors.

Solution was found here:
https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/3212

Answer (score 2):

For those working on macOS run from a terminal window..

```
- /Applications/Python\ 3.6/Install\Certificates.command
```

Answer (score 2):

This command worked for me

```
pip3 install --trusted-host pypi.python.org  --upgrade http://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-1.0.0-py3-none-any.whl
```

I made the request as http instead of https and I was able to bypass the ssl check.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need some security certificates.

Please try the following command.

```
sudo pip install requests[security]
```

If you get any error message, please uninstall and reinstall **python-requests**.

```
sudo pip uninstall requests
sudo apt-get install python-requests
```

I hoped it will give you the certificates you need.
Thanks.

Comment: issue still stands :/

I've reinstalled python-requests using apt-get. hitting sudo pip install requests[security] did nothing, so I've tried --upgrade and this is result:

    AssertionError: version mismatch, 0.9.2 != 1.5.0

    ----------------------------------------
  Rolling back uninstall of cryptography
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-R05Y91/cryptography/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-BR_et.... 

do you have any idea?

Comment: Please try the following link...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34085552/sslerror-bad-handshake-python-requests

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem too, and in my case using curl to download manually didn't fix the problem. Curl reported this:

```
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: certificate is not yet valid
```

The problem in my case turns out to have been **my VM's clock** not being *in sync with the internet time servers*. Resetting my VM's clock so the datetime was correct fixed the problem, and I was able to go right back to installing straight from pip.

I've added this note to [a related GitHub issue filed for TensorFlow](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1553). [This Unix StackExchange question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115563/how-to-ignore-certificate-is-not-yet-valid-errors) ultimately led me to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I used Anaconda to run "py -m pip install --upgrade tensorflow" and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try to upgrade your pip version with another mirror.

```
pip install --upgrade pip -i https://mirrors.aliyun.com/pypi/simple/
```

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if the date on your computer is wrong. Check with the command

```
date
```

I got it when it was set to August but the true date was in December. I corrected it with

```
sudo date 12191148
```

for December 19th 11:48 but obviously use the correct date for when you are.