# SSL certificate verify failed with python requests library

Tags: python, ssl-certificate, python-requests

We have this local site which has recently just updated its certificate. I saved the certificates in a `certs.pem` file and tried to connect it with some tools. Below operations are done on a Ubuntu 14.10 box.

When I run:

```
openssl s_client -connect mylocalsite:8080 -verify 9 -CAfile certs.pem
```

I get `Verify return code: 0 (ok)`, then I run:

```
wget https://mylocalsite:8080 --ca-certificate=certs.pem
```

I get:

`--2016-06-15 01:53:00--  https://mylocalsite:8080/
Resolving mylocalsite (mylocalsite)... 10.41.13.26
Connecting to mylocalsite (mylocalsite)|10.41.13.26|:8080... connected.`

So the certificate seems to work OK, then I use requests 2.10.0 with python 3.4.3 on the same box:

```
import requests
requests.get('https://mylocalsite:8080', verify='/path/to/certs.pem')
```

I get

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:600)
```

I'm completely new to SSL related things. What could possibly go wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: Could be related to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34085552/sslerror-bad-handshake-python-requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `openssl s_client -connect` is happy with "only" having the correct certificate but you need to pass the whole chain to requests' `verify` parameter (though both are using the same library under the hood, of course).

**SSL support in requests needs some *serious* revamp (and it's being worked on AFAIK)**