# error while installing graphlab in ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, machine-learning, pip, graphlab

I am getting the following error while installing graphlab in ubuntu 14.04. I already spent lot of time to solve this problem by googling it. can any one help me to solve this prblem.

Error:

```
ramy@ramy-Aspire-4739Z:~$ sudo pip install --upgrade https://get.graphlab.com/GraphLab-Create/2.1/mohangtrichy@gmail.com/<KEY>/GraphLab-Create-License.tar.gz
Downloading/unpacking https://get.graphlab.com/GraphLab-Create/2.1/mohangtrichy@gmail.com/<KEY>/GraphLab-Create-License.tar.gz
Cleaning up...
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 278, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1198, in prepare_files
    do_download,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1376, in unpack_url
    self.session,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 546, in unpack_http_url
    resp = session.get(target_url, stream=True)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 467, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 237, in request
    return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 455, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 558, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/adapters.py", line 385, in send
    raise SSLError(e)
SSLError: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:510: error:14077438:SSL    routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert internal error

Storing debug log for failure in /home/ramy/.pip/pip.log
ramy@ramy-Aspire-4739Z:~$
```

Answer (score 0):

> Requests can verify SSL certificates for HTTPS requests, just like a
>   web browser. To check a host’s SSL certificate, you can use the verify
>   argument:

And if you want to avoid the `SSLError` you can find the `requests` part and change verify to **False**:

```
requests.get('https://google.com', verify=False)
```

Another way reinstall `certifi` module:

```
sudo pip uninstall -y certifi
sudo pip install certifi==2015.04.28
```

Have a look at these questions:

[Python Requests throwing up SSLError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10667960/python-requests-throwing-up-sslerror)

[SSLError: bad handshake, Python requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34085552/sslerror-bad-handshake-python-requests)