# ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:833)

Tags: python, sockets, network-programming

I am trying to create TLS connection with a server. My simple script is below. However, when I run it, I get this error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tls_client.py", line 28, in <module>
    sslSocket.connect((domain, 443))
  File "C:\Python36\lib\ssl.py", line 1100, in connect
    self._real_connect(addr, False)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\ssl.py", line 1091, in _real_connect
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Python36\lib\ssl.py", line 1068, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Python36\lib\ssl.py", line 689, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:833)
```

The script:

```
   import socket, ssl
    context = ssl.SSLContext(protocol = ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_CLIENT)
    context.set_ciphers('ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256')
    context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_OPTIONAL
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sslSocket = context.wrap_socket(s, server_hostname = 'www.google.com')
    sslSocket.connect((domain, 443))
```

What is the cause of the problem? I tried couple of websites like `www.verisign.com` but I also get the same error.

**EDIT:**
I do not want to turn verify_mode off. I need it on. I think `google.com` and `verisign.com` have verifiable certificates.

**EDIT 2:**
Based on a solution in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27835619/urllib-and-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-error) provided:
I run pip install certifi
Then tried to run this command in Windows command but get an error:

```
>/Applications/Python\ 3.6/Install\ Certificates.comman
'/Applications/Python\' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: You don't want the accepted answer there (which is for a cross-platform Python 2.7 problem, rather than the Windows-specific 3.x problem, and explains how to do exactly what you don't want to do); scroll down to the Windows-specific answer, currently ranked third. (They really shouldn't all be piled into a single question like that, but…)

Comment: You can also probably use the Mac solution (currently ranked second) even though you're not on a Mac, but you'll need to `pip install certifi` instead of finding it pre-installed.

Comment: If you want to understand more about what's going on, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27826829/908494). (The details in that answer will not apply to you, but the way Steffen Ulrich gathered those details, and what they mean, are very similar.)

Comment: I run `pip install certifi` but didn't help.

Comment: Just installing `certifi` won't do anything; you have to use `certifi` the way the linked answer describes after installing it.