# SSL certificate verify failed and permission error on Install Certificates.command

Tags: python-3.x, ssl, certifi

I'm trying to run

```
from urllib.request import urlretrieve
url = "https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~./enron/enron_mail_20150507.tgz" 
urlretrieve(url, filename="../enron_mail_20150507.tgz")
```

to download the dataset. I get an SSL certificate verify fail error, which is solved in this question: [ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:749)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41691327/ssl-sslerror-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certificate-verify-failed-ssl-c) by running

```
/Applications/Python\ 3.6/Install\ Certificates.command
```

This gives me an error:

```
 -- pip install --upgrade certifi
Collecting certifi
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/56/9d/1d02dd80bc4cd955f98980f28c5ee2200e1209292d5f9e9cc8d030d18655/certifi-2018.10.15-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: certifi
  Found existing installation: certifi 2018.4.16
    Uninstalling certifi-2018.4.16:
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/certifi-2018.4.16.dist-info/DESCRIPTION.rst'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

I tried changing the command code but its write-protected so I figured I shouldn't mess with it. So I ran

```
pip install --upgrade certifi
```

and it updated, but when I try to download the Enron data again I still get the same message. It seems as if the command gets caught up on the older version of certifi. I have Python 2.7 and 3.6 on this computer for some reason so I ran `pip3` because that works sometimes but still am getting the same error.

Comment: Please check which version of OpenSSL is used by Python, i.e. `python -c 'import ssl;print(ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION)'`. If it is less than OpenSSL 1.0.2 (i.e. 1.0.1, 1.0.0 or even 0.9.8) then it is likely [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27804710/python-urllib2-ssl-error/27826829#27826829) since there are also different possible trust path [according to SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.cs.cmu.edu).

Comment: I am running OpenSSL 1.0.2.